# SQL CE 4.0 Datatypes and SQL server 2012 datatypes mapping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

Can someone please help us in establishing mapping of SQL CE 4.0 Data Types and SQL server 2012

Though we found following

1. SQL CE and SQL Server 2000 ([here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237850(v=sql.80).aspx))
2. .NET and SQL 2012([here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174642(v=sql.110).aspx))
3. OLEDB and SQL CE
4. SQL Server CE Data Type Mapping from ADOX

Comment: have you gone through https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140(v=sql.110).aspx ?

Comment: Welcome @Vikas :)  , please mark upvote to comment as its useful to you.

Comment: @Disha it seems it also need previlage (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) . Unfortunately i don't have it.

Comment: ok, no issue , enjoy development :)